# Brace and label on top of graph

Tags: pgfplots

I have a plot of some confidence interval corresponding to some points. I want to somehow highlight that some points - say $x_1,x_2,x_3$ - all belong to the same set $M$. My idea was to put a horizontal brace at the bottom (or top) of the graph with a label $M$. Any help in implementing this, or alternative ideas is welcome. Thanks.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1],
\centering
\begin{axis}[
height=7cm,
width=13cm,  
  ymax=5,
  ymin=0,
  xmin=0.5,
  xmax=10,
  axis y line*=left,
  axis x line*=bottom,
  xticklabels={$x_1$,$x_2$,$x_2$,$x_3$, $x_4$,$x_5$,$x_6$,$x_7$,$x_8$, $x_9$},xtick={1,...,10},
  x tick label style={anchor=north}]
\addplot+[only marks][error bars/.cd,y dir=both, y explicit]
coordinates {
(10,0.23333) +- (0.5,-0.2)
};
\addplot[dashed] coordinates {(0,0) (10,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ and which packages have to be loaded in order to make your code snippet minimally compilable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To highlight that points $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ belong to the same set $M$, you can add a horizontal brace below those points along with the label "$M$". You can achieve this using the brace decoration from TikZ. Here's how you can modify your existing TikZ code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
  height=7cm,
  width=13cm,  
  ymax=5,
  ymin=0,
  xmin=0.5,
  xmax=10.5,
  axis y line*=left,
  axis x line*=bottom,
  xticklabels={$x_1$,$x_2$,$x_2$,$x_3$, $x_4$,$x_5$,$x_6$,$x_7$,$x_8$, $x_9$},
  xtick={1,...,10},
  x tick label style={anchor=north}]
\addplot+[only marks][error bars/.cd,y dir=both, y explicit]
coordinates {
  (10,0.23333) +- (0.58257,-0.2159)
  (9,1.4) +- (2.04003,0.75997)
  (8,1.1) +- (1.82293,0.47707)
  (7,1.3667) +- (2.0352,0.6981)
  (6,0.44667) +- (0.94558,-0.41225)
  (5,3.5) +- (0.59648,-0.59648)
  (4,0.9) +- (1.67431,0.42569)
  (3,1.5667) +- (0.09502,0.92835)
  (2,0.56667) +- (1.30495,-0.37162)
  (1,0.4) +- (1.06941,-0.26941)
};
\addplot[dashed] coordinates {(0,0) (10.5,0)};
\end{axis}
% Brace and label
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,mirror},xshift=-4pt,yshift=-5pt]
(1.8,0) -- (4.2,0) node [black,midway,yshift=-15pt] {$M$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```